# Check if element exists in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which is given below:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["type"]=> string(4) "item" } }
```

I'm using to the following code in an if statement to see if "item" exists in the array but it isn't been evaluated as true

```
if (array_key_exists('item', $_SESSION['type'])) 

    {
       //do something
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `in_array()` of course, as you're checking for a value and not an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its array in array. And function `array_key_exists` checks only one level deep, if the key exists. And your ked is 2 levels deep, so it cant return true, because there is key only "0".

And "item" is not key, but value; you have to use function `in_array` or `array_search`.

And also you should create your own function for that, because its array in array...

Answer (score 3):

`array_key_exists` checks the keys of the array, not the values; `"item"` is a value.

To check for the existence of values use either [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) (if you don't care about the key in case the item is found) or [`array_search`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) (if you want to know what the key for that item was). For example:

```
if (in_array("item", $_SESSION['type'])) // do something
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `in_array` to find if an element exists in an array.

`array_key_exists` checks if the key of the array is present or not