# Use the Rand() function to Generate random numbers except numbers in Array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to use the rand() function to generate random numbers except numbers in an array or in my database.

Comment: Roll a random number, check if it is in the array, if it is, roll again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if element exists in PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539942/check-if-element-exists-in-php-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$not = [1, 4, 9];
$min = 1;
$max = 10;

do {
    $random = random_int($min, $max);
} while(in_array($random, $not));
var_dump($random);
```

The `$not` array can be populated from the database if you need to, but I have hardcoded it for this answer.
The `$min` and `$max` are used to set the upper and lower inclusive bounds of the random function.